# NodeJs how to share socket.io between main and child process?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, child-process

Suppose bellow is my `app.js`

```
var app = express();
let server = require("http").Server(app);

let io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
require("./forked-background-process")(io);
```

and following is `forked-background-process` that create a forked process

```
let schedule = require("node-schedule");
   module.exports = io => {
     schedule.scheduleJob("40 9 11 * * *", async function() {
     const jobAlertForkedProcess = fork('./startup/schedule-jobs');
     await jobAlertForkedProcess.send(2, io);
       jobAlertForkedProcess.on('message', (sum) => {
       jobAlertForkedProcess.kill();
     });
  });
}
```

and this is my forked process content `startup/schedule-jobs`:

```
process.on('message', async (type, io) => {

});
```

But this cause the following error `This handle type cannot be sent at ChildProcess.target._send`

Comment: You can't share an instance of socket.io between processes but you can scale it using [`socket.io-redis`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) as an adapter.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts with this adapter, how about its client side listener? They both have the same listener ? And could you please explain it with an example that match with my condition ?